# Extracting tables from pdf in R

Tags: r, pdf

I need to extract tables from a pdf. Here's the link

https://ainfo.cnptia.embrapa.br/digital/bitstream/item/155505/1/doc-202-1.pdf

I want to extract tables from page 15 - page 21. All of these tables have the same structure (18 columns) and headings. Here's a snapshot of a single table.
      [image]

In each table, I am only interested in columns 6 - 8 and 17 column:  `Ciclo`, `Graus Dias/dias`, Epcaja de Plantion`and`Regiao de adaptacao`

Here's what I did:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tabulizer)

out <- extract_tables("mydocument.pdf"), pages = c(15:21))

# this gives me a list of 7 tables. 

temp <- data.frame(out[[1]]) # taking the first table as an example
temp %>% dplyr::select(X3, X4, X5, X12) # these are the columns corresponding to `Ciclo`, `Graus Dias/dias`, Epcaja de Plantion` and `Regiao de adaptacao`

# this is a snapshot of first table
```

[image]

However, when I extract the 7th table:

```
  temp <- data.frame(out[[7]])

#  Column 1: 4 are merged into a single column.
```

[image]

In summary, the `extract_tables` function is not doing consistent column position and merging columns in some tables. How Can I fix it such that I have
a combined table with columns Ciclo`,`Graus Dias/dias`, Epcaja de Plantion` and `Regiao de adaptacao`  in one csv file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a data prep and wrangling problem, and not a parsing issue in my experience, as the parsing algorithms of tabulizer don't offer much leeway apart from changing between methods, in this case. From what I can see when I try to extract your tables its not only the table of page No. 7 that is incorrectly parsed. Every page is parsed differently but all the data seem to be retained. I can see that your first table has 13 columns, second 17, 3rd 12, 4th 10 and the last three 11 columns. What i would propose to do instead is to parse each page individually and perform data cleaning according to your desired output on each of them and then bind them together. This is a lengthy process and very specific to each table parsed so i will only provide an example script:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tabulizer)
# I create a dummy list to iterate through all the pages and push a data.frame in
result <- list()
for (i in 15:21){
  out <- as.data.frame(extract_tables("mydocument.pdf", page = i, method = 'stream'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  result[[i]] <- out
}
# Remove excess list items -
# there is probably a better way to do this from within the for loop
result <- result[-(1:14)]

## ------- DATA CLEANING OPERATIONS examples:
# Remove top 3x lines from the first page of table1 not part of data
result[[1]] <- result[[1]][-(1:3),]
# Perform data cleaning operations such as split/ merge columns according to your liking
# for instance if you want to split column X1 into 4 (as in your original post), you can do that by splitting by whitespace
result[[1]] <- separate(result[[1]], 1, into = c('X1.1','X1.2','X1.3', 'X1.4'),sep = ' ', remove = TRUE)

## ---- After data cleaning operations:
# Bind all dataframes (they should have equal number of columns by now into one and make sure the colnames match as well)
df <-bind_rows(result)
# Write your output csv file
write.csv(df, 'yourfilename.csv')
```

Also you might wanna take a look at the different parsing methods of tabulizer (I have set it at 'stream' here since this by my experience usually yields the best results, but maybe 'lattice' would work better for some of the tables).

Comment: tabulizer is being deprecated, would be nice to have a new solution not using tabulizer